# How to extract json Responce using json path extractor?

Tags: json, jmeter

I have below JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "CoID":"123",
        "OfflineStatus":"12",
        "PeriodID":"212",
        "ReportDate":"2\/6\/2015 12:00:00 AM",
        "TemplateID":"2114"
    },
    {
        "CoID":"21",
        "OfflineStatus":"11",
        "PeriodID":"3073",
        "ReportDate":"4\/30\/2015 12:00:00 AM",
        "TemplateID":"385155"
    }
]
```

I want to get Period is:3073, I tried $..[-1:] here I am getting all the things like coid, offlinestatus, periodid, reportdate, etc.

How to get only **PeriodID**?

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOund Solution: Below Code worked for me.
**`$.[-1:].PeriodID`**

Comment: This simply extracts *the last* PeriodID value form the array.

Comment: @sbos61 6  Thats what i want

Answer (score 0):

Just use :

> $..PeriodID

And Match Number set to 2

See:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code using JSON extractor

```
$.[1].PeriodID
```

Comment: Thank you, i need latest period id depend on report date because it has varying response

Comment: then you can use $.[-1:].PeriodID